# Scrolling JTable Header

Tags: java, swing

I have a JTable with 60 rows (Fixed).

Everytime an event happens the cell inside that row is updated.

The event is trigged when a NFC Reader writes data on a card. That happens every 2 or 3 seconds.

If the card is written correctly or not the jTable is updated with the result (WRITE, ERRO).

The function to move the JTable to the position only receives the row number.

The scroll is now moved to that row position.

Problem is: After a few row updates the Header of even other rows appears on top of the selected focus row...

Like the Image below.

[image]

This are the codes that I already used. They all do the same...

```
//First code
tblViewCsv.requestFocus();
tblViewCsv.changeSelection(rownumber, 0, false, false);

//2nd code
tblViewCsv.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(rownumber, rownumber);
tblViewCsv.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(tblViewCsv.getCellRect(rownumber, 0, true)));

 //3rd code
 JViewport viewport = (JViewport) tblViewCsv.getParent();
 Rectangle rect = tblViewCsv.getCellRect(rownumber, 0, true);
 Rectangle viewRect = viewport.getViewRect();
 rect.setLocation(rect.x - viewRect.x, rect.y - viewRect.y);

 int centerX = (viewRect.width - rect.width) / 2;
 int centerY = (viewRect.height - rect.height) / 2;
 if (rect.x < centerX) {
     centerX = -centerX;
 }
 if (rect.y < centerY) {
     centerY = -centerY;
 }
 rect.translate(centerX, centerY);
 viewport.scrollRectToVisible(rect);
```

This is the only method that scrolls to the selected.

This only receives an indicator of row number.

The row number is correct in all cases.

```
 public void scrollPanel(int line) {
    tblViewCsv.changeSelection(line, 0, false, false);
    tblViewCsv.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(line, line);
    tblViewCsv.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(tblViewCsv.getCellRect(line, 0, true)));
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: `Everytime an event happens...................Normally that event happens every 2 or 3 secs` what is that event?? I mean can you please update your question with more detailed code or full code if possible

Comment: @RakibulIslam *"more detailed code or full code if possible"* It's best the OP post a [mcve] as an [edit] to the question. BTW - get that MCVE link by typing `[mcve]` in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

> The event is trigged when a NFC Reader writes data on a card. That happens every 2 or 3 seconds.

So I'm guessing this is a separate Thread running in the background.

So you need to:

1. use `table.scrollRectToVisible(..)` since you want to scroll the table in the viewport of the scrollpane.
2. make sure the code is executed on the Event Dispatch Thread by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. Read the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information about the EDT.

Comment: Thank you. Implemented as you suggested but the same result happened. Looks like a rendering problem.

Comment: @RicardoCaldas, I have never had problems updating the table from a background Thread. It is more likely a coding problem. Since you still haven't provided your [mvce] code demonstrating the problem, we can't offer any more help.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code you provided, i think you have to check:

```
if( rownumber>=0 ) {
   //Your code
}
```

Maybe is a rendering problem caused by a rownumber = -1.

Comment: The line is always > 0.. Starts at 1 and ends correct.